# Div elements change position randomly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm trying to do a tournament table with HTML and thought to use Bootstrap grid elements, here's how far i've come.

I can't add the picture of what i've done (too low rep) so i'll add a link to it
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OedPj.jpg

Currently I'm having two issues:

1) notice the row three, the MAINCOL has moved a bit, can't figure out why. As you can see WB2 is also not in the right position. -- Solved

2) How could I create border for empty element in row 2 (just right under WB1 or LB1). Right now i created a same div element, added text "BYE" and changed the color to white, for the border to apply

Here are the div's

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- 1 -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 stripeBOT colmaker nobr">LB1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 stripeBOT stripeDOWN stripeUP stripeTOP colmaker nobr">MAINCOL</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 stripeBOT colmaker nobr">WB1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>

    </div>
    <!-- 2 -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker stripeUP whitetext">BYE</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 stripeBOT stripeDOWN stripeUP colmaker nobr">MAINCOL</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker stripeDOWN whitetext">BYE</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 stripeBOT colmaker nobr">VF1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- 3 -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 stripeBOT stripeUP nobr">LB2</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 stripeBOT stripeDOWN stripeUP colmaker nobr">MAINCOL</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 stripeBOT stripeDOWN nobr">WB2</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>   
    </div>
    <!-- 4 -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 stripeBOT stripeDOWN stripeUP colmaker nobr">MAINCOL</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- 5 -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 stripeBOT stripeDOWN stripeUP colmaker nobr">MAINCOL</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 stripeBOT colmaker nobr">WB3</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- 6 -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 stripeBOT stripeDOWN stripeUP colmaker nobr">MAINCOL</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker stripeDOWN whitetext">BYE</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 stripeBOT colmaker nobr">VF2</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- 7 -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 stripeBOT stripeDOWN stripeUP colmaker nobr">MAINCOL</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 stripeBOT colmaker nobr stripeDOWN">WB4</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- 8 -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 stripeBOT stripeDOWN stripeUP colmaker nobr">MAINCOL</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- 9 -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 stripeBOT stripeDOWN stripeUP colmaker nobr">MAINCOL</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- 10 -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 stripeBOT stripeDOWN stripeUP colmaker nobr">MAINCOL</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- 11 -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 stripeBOT stripeDOWN stripeUP colmaker nobr">MAINCOL</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- 12 -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 stripeBOT stripeDOWN stripeUP colmaker nobr">MAINCOL</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- 13 -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 stripeBOT stripeDOWN stripeUP colmaker nobr">MAINCOL</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- 14 -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 stripeBOT stripeDOWN stripeUP colmaker nobr">MAINCOL</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- 15 -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 stripeBOT stripeDOWN stripeUP colmaker nobr">MAINCOL</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- 16 -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 stripeBOT stripeDOWN stripeUP colmaker nobr">MAINCOL</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 colmaker"></div>
    </div>
```

And here's the CSS (Bootstrap col-xs-1 not added from here)

```
 .stripeUP{
     border-left: 1px solid #000;
 }

 .stripeDOWN{
     border-right: 1px solid #000;
 }

 .stripeTOP{
     border-top: 1px solid #000;
 }

 .spacer{
     margin-top: 10px;
 }

 .colmaker{
     margin-right: 1px;
 }
.nobr { 
    white-space: nowrap;

}
.whitetext{
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Have you check that how your code works here? http://jsfiddle.net/nsd4rawh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you notice on your LB1 div you have

```
<div class="col-xs-1 stripeBOT colmaker nobr">LB1</div>
```

On your LB2 div you have

```
<div class="col-xs-1 stripeBOT stripeUP nobr">LB2</div>
```

So, add the class colmaker to the LB2 div

```
<div class="col-xs-1 stripeBOT colmaker stripeUP nobr">LB2</div>
```

Comment: Great, thanks for your help, just a little mistake slipped in unnoticed, thank you!
Any ideas about issue nr 2)?

Comment: you can keep the div and force the height to be equal to the others but as an empty div

Answer (score 0):

Try REMOVING this from your css:

```
.colmaker{
  margin-right: 1px;
 }
```

Comment: Yup was just about to say that! Here's http://jsfiddle.net/pkwum9kL/ to play with =)

Answer (score 0):

Try This One, Just Made Some Changes In CSS

http://www.bootply.com/9RLR3by3F7

Answer (score 0):

I think you're taking the wronk approach.

if i were you i would use a `table` :

```css
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
    width: 500px;
}

td{
    width: 100px;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}

.stripeUP{
     border-left: 1px solid #000;
 }

 .stripeDOWN{
     border-right: 1px solid #000;
 }

 .stripeTOP{
     border-top: 1px solid #000;
 }

 .stripeBOTTOM{
     border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
 }

.stripe{
     border: 1px solid #000;
 }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>LB1</td>
        <td class="stripe">MAINCOL</td>
        <td>WB1</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="stripeBOTTOM"></td>
        <td class="stripeUP stripeTOP"></td>
        <td class="stripe">MAINCOL</td>
        <td class="stripeDOWN stripeTOP"></td>
        <td class="stripeBOTTOM">VF1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="stripeUP stripeBOTTOM">LB2</td>
        <td class="stripe">MAINCOL</td>
        <td class="stripeDOWN stripeBOTTOM">WB2</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="stripe">MAINCOL</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>LB3</td>
        <td class="stripe">MAINCOL</td>
        <td>WB3</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="stripeBOTTOM"></td>
        <td class="stripeUP stripeTOP"></td>
        <td class="stripe">MAINCOL</td>
        <td class="stripeDOWN stripeTOP"></td>
        <td class="stripeBOTTOM">VF2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="stripeUP stripeBOTTOM">LB4</td>
        <td class="stripe">MAINCOL</td>
        <td class="stripeDOWN stripeBOTTOM">WB4</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="stripe">MAINCOL</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="stripe">MAINCOL</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="stripe">MAINCOL</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="stripe">MAINCOL</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Imho, wrong approach as it is a bad practice.

If you want a table, Just use bootstraps table css --> http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables
Some small tutorial -> http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tables.asp

Unless you know what you are doing, Never change margins/paddings on bootstrap elements (especially main elements like containers/rows/col) otherwise you break everything up.

Do not forget to close your container otherwise everything breaks up.